# Visual Studio 2019 and AWS: "not a supported code page" when doing a .NET Core 2.1 project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, amazon-web-services, servicestack, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I created a template project for ServiceStack using the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57511810/178143), basically creating a .NET Core 2.1 project.

When I used the "Publish to AWS Elastic Beanstalk..." option in Visual Studio (using AWS Toolkit) I end up with the following error, regardless if I create a new environment or use an existing one:

> ...caught exception during deployment package creation - 1 is not a
>   supported code page.
>  
>   Parameter name: codepage 
>   ..build of project, archive failed, abandoning deployment

However, if I instead of creating a .NET Core projet using the command line as described in the SO answer linked about, I create a .NET Framework version (using a template `ServiceStack ASP.NET Empty`), then publishing to AWS works without problems:

> ....creating new version 'v20190815201511' for application
>   'DrivingLicenseApi ...requesting update of environment
>   'DrivingLicenseApi-dev' with application version 'v20190815201511'
>   Publish to AWS Elastic Beanstalk environment 'DrivingLicenseApi-dev'
>   completed successfully

I have looked around, and others have run into the same error, but I have been unable to figure out whats it about.

I am running dotnet version `3.0.100-preview5-011568` and `Visual Studio 2019 v 16.2.0 preview 1.0` on Win10. The ServiceStack version is the latest from NuGet, `5.6`.

EDIT: Updated to Visual Studio 2019 v 16.3.0 preview 2, but the error is the same.

Comment: Could you look at your "Build and IIS Deployment Settings" screen and set your Default Project Build to "Build" @Ted

Comment: Not sure where that is. Configuration manager didnt seem to be it. Where do I find that?

Comment: You'll probably want to have a look at this -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/tutorial-import-publish-settings-iis?view=vs-2019

Comment: Thx, but this isn applicable to me. I am running a .NET Core self-hosted thing; i dont do any of those steps.

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to state the Origin of this issue.

There is a [blogpost](http://community.sharpdevelop.net/forums/t/19065.aspx) where the answer given states that changing the regional language seems to solve the problem (there is a long thread there).

Another on [github](https://github.com/chef/chef-dk/issues/1290) states the same regarding the language, when the op changed the keyboard and location settings.

It all seems to come down to unsupported language issue, though the origin of the issue is unclear still.

Maybe if you play with the language settings it will work for you as well on .Net Core 2.1, give it a try, no harm will come (or so I believe).